# How does UART communication work between two devices?

Tags: multithreading, microcontroller, communication, uart

In one of my project, I have a nano-computer (embedded Linux) which is connected to a microcontroller with an UART connection.

Both do some process on their own, but sometimes the nano-computer needs to send data on the UART and vice versa.

I suppose that if A wants to communicate with B, B needs to be listening, right ? How do I know when to listen, and when to talk ? 
Do I need to have a special thread running in parallel in both of my devices only responsible for UART communication, while they do other stuff ? 
If I missed a message, is there a buffer which is filled that I can read when I am ready ?

Thanks for your advices. :)

Comment: In UART communication, two UARTs communicate directly with each other. The transmitting UART converts parallel data from a controlling device like a CPU into serial form, transmits it in serial to the receiving UART, which then converts the serial data back into parallel data for the receiving device. Only two wires are needed to transmit data between two UARTs. Please kindly read how UART works.

Answer (score 0):

'A' and 'B' are listening all time. You have to enable the UART receive interupt.
Maybe this link will explain the basics: [UART basics](http://www.circuitbasics.com/basics-uart-communication/)

Answer (score 0):

Connected and initialized correctly the hardware has a tx and rx on both sides tx to rx.  So both sides are listening all the time from a hardware perspective.  The operating system likely has a driver and a buffer that is accumulating that input all the time.  BUT if you have no software that is asking for the data coming in then you wont see it.  You do need some software monitoring the uart if you will (through drivers and operating system usually) so that you can see what the other side sends at any given time.  You do this on both ends of the connection if that is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that are used.

In the past, it was common to use hardware flow control. This uses an additional wire in each direction. The sender waits until the wire indicates the receiver is ready. When the receiver is not ready to receive data, it signals the other side. Hardware would buffer at least one byte and, if the buffer was full, signal the other side not to send over this wire.

This is less common today. UARTs are so slow relative to modern hardware and large buffers are so cheap and easy to provide that there is no longer an issue. The sender just fills the receiver's hardware buffer and the receiver empties the hardware buffer periodically. Software would have to ignore the buffer for a long time for it to overflow.

An intermediate solution is to use flow control in the data flow. Generally, two characters are reserved, one to stop the flow and one to resume it. The receiver sends a flow control character to the sender if its buffer is getting close to full and another one if its buffer is getting close to empty. This is really only useful if the data flow doesn't need to handle binary data. This is extremely rare and was traditionally used primarily for connections that had a human on one end. You could also pause the flow if the information was coming faster than you could read it.

Generally, the protocols used are tolerant of overflow and include some form of high-level acknowledgement and/or retransmission as appropriate. One device might wait for the other side to send some kind of response to its command and, if it doesn't get one, retry the command. The protocol is designed not to do anything terrible if a command is received twice since it might be the reply that's lost.